# Multiple constraints with same constraint name, different namespaces

Tags: marklogic

According to the Search Developers Guide:
Each constraint is named, and the name must be unique across all operators and constraints in your options node.

We are using a content enrichment package that produces output like this:

```
`<TM360:Measurements Measurements="Distance">
    <Measurements:Distance Amount="3" Unit="inches"/>
</TM360:Measurements>
<TM360:Measurements Measurements="Volume">
    <Measurements:Volume Amount="5.0" Unit="liters"/>
</TM360:Measurements>`
```

Looking at "Amount":
The attribute localName is not unique, but the element that contains it is unique.

Is there a way get around the constraint name uniqueness limitation to build a constrained search, say, "Amount: 5.0" that would include the indexes over both entries above?

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom constraint to achieve this. I succeeded in doing this using the following three scripts:

- setup-db.xqy
- search.xqy
- custom-constraint.xqy

Here's the setup script, which creates the two "Amount" range indexes and adds a couple of sample documents (test1.xml and test2.xml):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy" ;

declare namespace TM360        = "http://example.com/TM360";
declare namespace Measurements = "http://example.com/Measurements";

declare function local:make-amount-index($parent-name) {
  admin:database-range-element-attribute-index(
    (: data type       :) "decimal",
    (: parent name     :) "http://example.com/Measurements",$parent-name,
    (: attribute name  :) "", "Amount",
    (: collation       :) "",
    (: value positions :) false()
  )
};

(: Set up the indexes (or you can add these via the Admin UI) :)
let $dbid       := xdmp:database(),
    $rangespec1 := local:make-amount-index("Distance"),
    $rangespec2 := local:make-amount-index("Volume"),
    $config     := admin:get-configuration(),
    $config     := admin:database-add-range-element-attribute-index($config, $dbid, $rangespec1),
    $config     := admin:database-add-range-element-attribute-index($config, $dbid, $rangespec2)
return
  admin:save-configuration($config)

,

(: Add some sample docs :)
xdmp:document-insert("/test1.xml",
  <TM360:Measurements Measurements="Distance">
      <Measurements:Distance Amount="3" Unit="inches"/>
  </TM360:Measurements>),

xdmp:document-insert("/test2.xml",
  <TM360:Measurements Measurements="Volume">
      <Measurements:Volume Amount="5.0" Unit="liters"/>
  </TM360:Measurements>)
```

Below is search.xqy, which makes two searches:

- `search:search("Amount:3",$options)`
- `search:search("Amount:5",$options)`

Note in particular the $options node, which defines the custom constraint:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
       at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options :=
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="Amount">
      <custom facet="false">
        <parse apply="parse-amount"
               ns="http://example.com/custom-constraint"
               at="/custom-constraint/custom-constraint.xqy">
        </parse>
      </custom>
    </constraint>
  </options>;

(: matches test1.xml :)
search:search("Amount:3",$options),

(: matches test2.xml :)
search:search("Amount:5",$options)
```

And finally, here's the custom-constraint.xqy code, which is what translates the constraint text into a cts OR query across the two Amount indexes:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace my = "http://example.com/custom-constraint";

declare namespace Measurements = "http://example.com/Measurements";

declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";

(: Convert the constraint text into an OR query against "Distance" and "Volume" :)
declare function my:parse-amount($constraint-qtext as xs:string,
                                 $right as schema-element(cts:query))
        as schema-element(cts:query)
{
  let $value := xs:decimal($right//cts:text)
  return
    <cts:or-query>{
      my:make-amount-query("Distance",$value),
      my:make-amount-query("Volume"  ,$value)
    }</cts:or-query>
};


declare function my:make-amount-query($parent-name, $value) {
  cts:element-attribute-range-query(
    (: parent name    :) QName("http://example.com/Measurements", $parent-name),
    (: attribute name :) xs:QName("Amount"),
    (: operator       :) "=",
    (: value          :) $value
  )
};
```

If you want your constraint to function as a facet also, then you'd additionally need to implement the start-facet and finish-facet functions (and augment the  definition in your options node accordingly. The [Search Developer's Guide](http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/search-dev-guide.pdf) includes an example of how to do this.

Comment: This looks like the most viable solution for our project.  Thanks for the information (and code).

Answer (score 2):

For best results you will have to refactor or enrich that XML. The search API is designed to take best advantage of MarkLogic's indexing features, which are based on QNames. The XML you have today has one element QName: TM360, and a few attribute QNames, none of which are strongly selective.

You can use XSLT or a recursive transform to reformat that XML. I would suggest that you target something like this:

```
<dist:inches xmlns:dist="ns://fubar.distance">3</dist:inches>
<vol:liters xmlns:vol="ns://fubar.volume">5.0</vol:liters>
```

As a side effect, this lets you write more concise XPath queries, and allows much more specific schema types for your nodes.

This use case is probably contrived, but you might also want to consider normalizing all these measurements into a standard subset of SI units, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgs, so that comparisons are easier.

Answer (score 1):

It would be relatively straight-forward with cts functions. You could do something like:

```
declare namespace Measurements = "http://example.com/Measurements";

cts:search(doc(), cts:element-attribute-value-query(
  (xs:QName("Measures:Distance"), xs:QName("Measures:Volume")),
  xs:QName("Amount"),
  $myamount
))
```

Luckily, you can also express that as a single search constraint as of MarkLogic 8.0-5, and use that with `search:search` or the (nowadays) built-in REST api:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace TM360        = "http://example.com/TM360";
declare namespace Measurements = "http://example.com/Measurements";

xdmp:document-insert(
  "/amount3.xml",
  <TM360:Measurements Measurements="Distance">
    <Measurements:Distance Amount="3" Unit="inches"/>
  </TM360:Measurements>
),
xdmp:document-insert(
  "/amount5.xml",
  <TM360:Measurements Measurements="Volume">
    <Measurements:Volume Amount="5.0" Unit="liters"/>
  </TM360:Measurements>
)

;

import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
       at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options :=
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="Amount">
      <value>
        <element ns="http://example.com/Measurements" name="Distance"/>
        <element ns="http://example.com/Measurements" name="Volume"/>
        <attribute ns="" name="Amount"/>
      </value>
    </constraint>
  </options>;

(: matches /amount3.xml :)
search:search("Amount:3",$options),

(: matches /amount5.xml :)
search:search("Amount:5.0",$options)
```

If you have range indexes for all element-attribute combinations, you can also use a range constraint, like suggested by Evan..

HTH!